# MongoDB with .NetCore2 performance issue

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, async-await

After migrating a running .AspNet app to .NetCore2 I realised heavy performance issues with any async controller calls.

Testing performance was done with this simple line of code:

```
// GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<string>> Get()
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var sw1 = new Stopwatch();

        var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(m => m.IsTrash, false);

        sw.Start();
        var list = await _context.Posts().Find(filter: filter).ToListAsync();
        sw.Stop();

        sw1.Start();
        list = _context.Posts().Find(filter: filter).ToList();
        sw1.Stop();

        result.Add(String.Format("GetPostsAsync: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        result.Add(String.Format("GetPostsSync: {0}ms", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        return result;
    }
```

The Post entity is just a simple class with string body and ObjectId as BSONID. There are just 100 items in the collection.

So result is:

```
["GetPostsAsync: 315ms","GetPostsSync: 4ms"]
```

Called this about 100 times in a loop. The very first call takes nearly seconds.

Using VisualStudio for MacOS, NetCore2.0 & NetCore2.1Preview. Are there any bottlenecks or known issues? Thx in advise.

Comment: Running same code on a Windows10 machine:
["GetPostsAsync: 22ms","GetPostsSync: 5ms"]

Comment: Performance issues should be reported to the appropriate project teams.

Comment: Which mongo driver you're using?

Comment: Using latest 3.6 driver. Tested with CorePreview2.1 and Core2.0. Same results. Running unter Windows or Linux (NGINX) speed is 150x times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Using task/ async does not mean make the code run faster.

Async will create a task and push it in thread pool to keep track the handling process.
for example, create task and get the result from task take 200ms, and the query for a short table take 50ms. this means using async will take 250ms, using sync code just take 50ms.

The async task will show their advance when the query take a very long time like 5mins. And the thread pool will take care when the result return. Server dont wait all 5mins. It can do other task in stead of waiting all that time